Create a text field that block all special characters but enables a few
I'm adding a text input formatter as extension, What is the regex for this case:

Allow english/arabic letters and numbers.

Block all special characters except DOT. DASH- SINGLEQUOTE'


here is my regex:
static final RegExp  _allowFewSpecialCharacters = RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z0-9\u0600-\u06FF\p{L}\p{Nd}\s\!\.\-\']");

Method:
 static TextInputFormatter filterSpecialCharacters() {
  return FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(_allowFewSpecialCharacters);
 }

usage:
TextField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Allow few characters'),
          inputFormatters: [AppTextInputFormatters.filterSpecialCharacters()],
        ),

My approach is not working, what is wrong and how this task can be accomplished ?

Define "special character"…

@deceze take a look https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/special-character/#:~:text=A%20special%20character%20is%20one,marks%20are%20considered%20special%20characters.

Declare your RegExp as:
final RegExp _allowFewSpecialCharacters =
      RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\u0600-\u06FF.\-']*$");

Note that:

\u0600-\u06FF: matches Arabic characters in the Unicode range.
.: matches the dot.
\-: matches a dash (the backslash is used to escape the dash since it has a special meaning inside character classes).
': matches a single quote.


You regex is working correct but the field will be automatically cleared if user typed a black listed character, in this case try to use RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9\u0600-\u06FF.-' ']+') i solved it using this regex
